# What effect does Coat of Arms have on face-down creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing a Sliver deck vs a co-worker today, and he played an illusion deck with [Ixidron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ixidron). I was having a hard time grasping how [Coat of Arms](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coat%20of%20Arms) would work with Ixidron turning everything face down.

Ixidron basically says all face-down cards are creatures. Is creature a type that Coat of Arms would be pairing with and make everything huge, or would coat of arms essentially do nothing to all of those face down cards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From that same page (emphasis mine):

> Creatures turned face down by Ixidron are 2/2 creatures with no text, no name, **no subtypes**, no expansion symbol, and no mana cost.

"Creature type" is a shorthand for a creature-specific subtype (205.3m in the Comprehensive Rules). Face-down creatures have no creature type, so Coat of Arms does not affect them.

Comment: So, you are essentially saying that **Coat of Arms** specifically effects only subtypes and since it only gets a base type of **creature** then it has no subtype and therefore coat of arms doesn't work on it?

Comment: @dphil: Correct. Creature types are a subtype.

Comment: @dphil, "Creature type" is short for "creature subtype", of which Sliver is an example.

Comment: The shorthand is codified in comprehensive rule 205.3m *Creatures and tribals share their lists of subtypes; these subtypes are called creature types*

Comment: @ChadMiller It might be good to reference that shortcut, and state in your answer that 'creature type' refers to certain subtypes.

Comment: You guys are allowed to edit, you know. But will do. ;)